# How to override font weights with Vuetify and Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

How do I override the default `font-weight` presets with **Vuetify** and **Nuxt**?

I tried by adding this in my `assets/variables.scss` but it's not working:

```
$font-weights: (
  regular: 900,
);
```

My `nuxt.config.js` file looks like this:

```
vuetify: {
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  treeShake: true,
  theme: {
    // dark: false,
    themes: {
      light: {},
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blue.darken2,
        accent: colors.grey.darken3,
        secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
        info: colors.teal.lighten1,
        warning: colors.amber.base,
        error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
        success: colors.green.accent3,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax to do a deep merge on the variable:

```
map-deep-merge(
  (
    'thin': 100,
    'light': 300,
    'regular': 400,
    'medium': 500,
    'bold': 700,
    'black': 900
  ),
  $font-weights
);
```

This example was directly from the [Vuetify search tool for variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#variable-api)

You can select `$vuetify` and see a list of the Vuetify instance variables and their configuration syntax.